Find matrix rows with common elements
Good morning everybody, first time for me here as Python beginner.
I have to solve the following problem: given a matrix as the one below, I need to find which rows have some nonzero elements in common in the same position (in this case row 0 and row 1 have the first element in common). I've already found the rows which are equal.
A = [[1 1 0 0 0 0],
     [1 0 0 0 0 0],
     [0 0 1 0 0 0],
     [0 0 0 1 1 1],
     [0 0 0 1 1 1]].

Sorry if I don't propose a solution and my formulation is not accurate, I have never used such codes before.
Thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is a List of Lists not a matrix in row/column sense. However it will raise an error because elements have to be comma-separated as [1,1,0....].

Thanks for the clarification, as I said I'm not an expert yet. Supposing I have a matrix in row/column sense, any suggestion?

it may need to get first row and compare it with all rows below, next it will need to get second row and compare with all rows below, etc.

The exact solution depends how you may want to present your results. This would be my approach resulting on a list of paired tuples for the associated elements.
First I consider transforming the list of lists to a numpy array, which is the main Python library for array computation and linear algebra. This will allow us to manipulate the object as if it was a matrix.
import numpy as np

A = [[1,1,0,0,0,0],
     [1,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,1,1],
     [0,0,0,1,1,1]]

A = np.array(A)

The next bit requires a bit of ploblem solving skills. One can note that two vectors have no 1s in common if the scalar product is 0, and conversely, they have 1s in common if the scalar product is >0. For example:

[1,1,0,0,0,0]x[1,0,0,0,0,0] = 1x1+1x0+0x0+0x0+0x0+0x0 = 1


[1,1,0,0,0,0]x[0,0,1,0,0,0] = 1x0+1x0+0x1+0x0+0x0+0x0 = 0

We could now search the rows with two nested loops to test if the scalar products of each is > 0. However, there is a much cleaner way to do this, all in one go. Note that multiplying the matrix by its transpose, Ax(A^t) = M, yields a matrix whose elements Mij are the scalar products of vi * vj. This means that we can obtain all the scalar products all at once by doing this multiplication which can be done by using numpy's matmul function and the '.T' syntax to get the transpose.
M = np.matmul(A, A.T)
M
>> array([[2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
          [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
          [0, 0, 0, 3, 3]])

Now the only thing remaing is to get the indexes (i,j) where Mij > 0 without repetition since Mij = vi x vj = vj x vi = Mji. To get the indexes where a condition is met, numpy has the where function which does that straigh forward and you can use as such:
rows, columns = np.where(M > 0)
rows, columns
>> (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], dtype=int64),
   array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4], dtype=int64))

This could already qualify as an answer. However, we still have repetition since we have (1,0) and (0,1) represented in the lists and we would like to present this in a more friendly way. So we finish by applying a list coprehension to merge all this together.
result = [(row, column) for row, column in zip(rows, columns) if row < column]
result
>> [(0, 1), (3, 4)]

I would encourage you to learn more about the numpy library, it is key if you want to work with arrays in Python. Good luck with your learning.
